# Замена подстроки в строке

Tags: javascript, строки

Доброго всем времени суток.
Извлекаю `href` в ссылке

```
var lnk = $('.el-buy').attr('href');
```

он мне возвращает вот такую строку

```
/catalog/43/615.html?action=ADD2BASKET&id=1186&bitrix_include_areas=Y&clear_cache=Y
```

где есть **`id=1186`**. ссылка может быть разная, но везде присутствует **`id`** и определённое количество цифр в нем. Подскажите как мне заменять эти цифры которые идут в **`id`** на свои. То есть по сути мне надо заменять в ссылке этот **`id`** ну а потом ссылку возвращать обратно с уже изменённым **`id`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет метод [replace](http://javascript.ru/String/replace) в javascript.

Comment: lnk=lnk.replace(/id=[^0-9]/g,id); я не знаю как запихнуть регулярное выражение в replace тоесть чтобы оно проверяло id=а потом проверка цыфр??

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант: получаешь ссылку, дважды разбиваешь её методом split(), сначала по '&', затем полученные элементы по '='. Находишь с id, меняешь значение, а потом склеиваешь с помощью join(). Ну или с помощью регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 2):

Все было просто как оказалось,

```
var lnk = $('.el-buy').attr('href');
lnk=lnk.replace(/id=\d+/g,"id="+id);
```

Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
function url_replace(url, id)
{
    var explode = url.split('&');

    for(var i in explode)
    {
        if(explode[i].match('id='))
        {
            explode[i] = explode[i].replace(explode[i], 'id=' + id);
        }
    }

    document.write(explode.join('&'));
    //в вашем случае - return explode.join('&');
}

url_replace('/catalog/43/615.html?action=ADD2BASKET&id=1186&bitrix_include_areas=Y&clear_cache=Y', '1234');
```

Comment: а как мне заменить теперь var lnk = $('.el-buy').attr('href');

Comment: как можно проще изъять id=и все цыфры идущие за ним, просто как-то сложновато через функцию.